# How to fill jtable with the right data from another table?

Tags: java, mysql, jtable

I have a [JTable](https://ibb.co/y5hnMGT) with 6 columns, the rows for the first 3 columns comes from table1(subject_records_bsit_first_year) and the last 3 will come from table2(evaluation_permission). The [two database](https://ibb.co/LZck2hG) table have two joined columns(subject_code and subject_title). I'm trying to fill the last 3 columns of my JTable with data from table2—using the db table connection to display the right data.

My code:

```
public static void loadFirstYearSubjectList() {
        
        ConnectionManager connectionManager = new ConnectionManager();
        //String sqlChooseStudent = "SELECT * FROM student_bsit_"+studentID.toLowerCase() +" WHERE year_level = '"+yearLevel+"'";
        try {
            Connection con = connectionManager.createConnection();
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM `subject_records_bsit_first_year` ORDER BY `subject_records_bsit_first_year`.`trimester_period` ASC";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            
            DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
            tableModel.addColumn("Subject Code");
            tableModel.addColumn("Subject Title");
            tableModel.addColumn("Trimester");
            tableModel.addColumn("Section");
            tableModel.addColumn("Professor");
            tableModel.addColumn("Evaluation");
            
            table.setModel(tableModel);
            
            TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
            columnModel.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(95);
            columnModel.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(266);
            columnModel.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(90);
            columnModel.getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(77);
            columnModel.getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(179);
            columnModel.getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(78);
            
            DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
            renderer.setBackground(new Color(120, 120, 120, 10));
            renderer.setOpaque(true);
            columnModel.getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(renderer);
            columnModel.getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(renderer);
            columnModel.getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(renderer);
            columnModel.getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(renderer);
            columnModel.getColumn(4).setCellRenderer(renderer);
            columnModel.getColumn(5).setCellRenderer(renderer);
            while (rs.next()) {
                String subjectCode = rs.getString("subject_code");
                String subjectTitle = rs.getString("subject_title");
                String trimesterPeriod = rs.getString("trimester_period");
                
                tableModel.addRow(new Object[] {subjectCode, subjectTitle, trimesterPeriod});
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
        } finally {
            try {
                connectionManager.closeConnection();
            } catch (Exception e2) {

            }
        }
    }
```

[table 2 data](https://ibb.co/r0w87v4)
I'm trying to display the section, subject_teacher and evaluation_permission from this table, this table is joined from another table that already displays the first 3 columns on my jtable. The two db table is joined with the same column names; subject_code and subject_title.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own implementation of [TableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) that is able to retrieve the data as you described above. Then use JTable's [setModel()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html#setModel(javax.swing.table.TableModel)) to make the JTable actually use your TableModel implementation.

An example how to use it is in the [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data).

Comment: Is my code wrong? should I restructure it? I don't understand your instruction, I'm only a student and this is a school project, I'm sorry I'm also having trouble explaining in english.

Comment: That's what I've been trying to do retrieve data from two db table and put them in jtable, I haven't get any luck or any clue how to do it as of yet. I've tried many tutorials one of them is using join statement I think, though I did not understand it. I was hoping to  get a simple example.

Comment: I added a tutorial you can follow. First try to understand how to get data into JTable, then return to your code and add the database stuff.

Comment: It gets complicated because the second table must use the data fetched from first table, I've seen anything I can, I've been trying to do this for a week now.

Comment: It's not simple join statement, I can't use WHERE for the second half of the query statement because I must use the data from the first half to match the jtable data using db table relation.

Comment: Why are coding communities like this? I understand that we must learn but a little example could really make huge difference, if this is being lazy it is not because I've been trying to do this for week and it's really frustrating to be given an instruction to something I don't understand or a documentation that is not really beginner friendly. Who reads oracle tutorials as a beginner.

Comment: Try to divide your problem into digestable chunks. One of them is about the data you want to display. That seems to involve several SQL tables/queries. Then figure out how you want to present the data. Currently my feeling is you want to present data from several SQL tables in one JTable. You know how to retrieve the data, now just learn how to present it to JTable so it gets displayed.
To be more open for the tutorial, forget about your complicated way to get the data. Just assume you already have it in RAM. Try the eample and, once understood apply it to your data fetching code.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT subject_records_bsit_first_year.subject_code,
       subject_records_bsit_first_year.subject_title,
       subject_records_bsit_first_year.trimester_period,
       evaluation_permission.section, evaluation_permission.subject_teacher,
       evaluation_permission.permission_status
FROM subject_records_bsit_first_year
INNER JOIN evaluation_permission
      ON subject_records_bsit_first_year.subject_code = evaluation_permission.subject_code;
```

Got what I'm trying to do, thanks for the help! Sometimes people learn from example.